# Sort every pair of rows by a reference row

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

I have the following file called `data` (the delimiters are spaces, but here I wrote tabs for the sake of clarity):

```
a   b   c   d   e   f   g
a   c   d   f   e
21  18  32  31  35
b   a   f   e   d   g
12  22  21  28  32  33
...
```

Starting from the second row, I would like each pair of rows to be sorted by matching the row that contains letters to the first row of the file (`a    b   c   d   e   f   g`), and preserving every pair letter-number, so the result be:

```
a   b   c   d   e   f   g
a   b   c   d   e   f   g
21  0   18  32  35  31  0
a   b   c   d   e   f   g
22  12  0   32  28  21  33
...
```

Please note that, for each pair of rows, there can be missing letters, e.g. in the `data` example there are two missing letters in the first pair of rows and one in the second pair. These letters are assigned a zero in the desired output.

So far, I have found the following code on the site:

```
while read line; do 
  sorted=$(sort -g -- <<< "${line// /$'\n'}")
  printf -- "${sorted//$'\n'/ }\n"
done < data
```

but it simply orders every line by alphabetic or numeric order:

```
a   b   c   d   e   f   g
a   c   d   e   f
18  21  31  32  35
a   b   d   e   f   g
12  21  22  28  32  33
...
```

Is there any way I can modify the code so it does it by matching the first row of the file, and preserving the letter-number pairs within each pair of rows?

Comment: Please specify whether every row pair has all of the letters in the header, or just some.  (i.e. could the data include a row with `f b d` and *no other letters*.)

Comment: Done, and yes, there can be missing letters, so f b d is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -wle '@h = split " ", <>;
           print "@h";
           until (eof) {
               ($cols, $vals) = (scalar <>, scalar <>);
               my %map;
               @map{ split " ", $cols } = split " ", $vals;
               print "@h";
               print join " ", map $_ // 0, @map{@h};
           }' -- data
```

- `-l` handles newlines in both input and output
- `@h` is the array of the "headers", i.e. the column names taken from the first line. See [split](http://p3rl.org/split).
- `%map` is a hash table, it maps the columns to the values.
- `@map{ list }` is a hash slice syntax. It returns the values corresponding to keys in the list in the same order.
- the `//` operator replaces [undef](http://p3rl.org/undef) (a missing value) with a 0.

Answer (score 0):

In awk, commented:

```
NR == 1 {
    # Store reference line in string for simple printing later
    ref_str = $0

    # Store reference line in array
    split($0, ref)

    # Number of elements in reference line
    nel = NF
    print
}

NR > 1 {
    # Read letters into array
    split($0, keys)
    getline

    # Create array with letter/number pairs for current line pair
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
        cur_line[keys[i]] = $i

    print ref_str

    # Loop over elements of reference line
    # Insert output field separator, except before first field
    # Print value from current line, or 0 if value is not in current line
    for (i = 1; i <= nel; ++i)
        out = out (i > 1 ? OFS : "") (cur_line[ref[i]] ? cur_line[ref[i]] : 0)

    print out

    # Delete array for current line; gawk: delete(cur_line)
    split("", cur_line)

    # Reset output line
    out = ""
}
```

The output is space-separated:

```
$ awk -f so.awk infile
a   b   c   d   e   f   g
a   b   c   d   e   f   g
21 0 18 32 35 31 0
a   b   c   d   e   f   g
22 12 0 32 28 21 33
```

But, for verification purposes, we can make the columns line up:

```
$ awk -f so.awk infile | column -t
a   b   c   d   e   f   g
a   b   c   d   e   f   g
21  0   18  32  35  31  0
a   b   c   d   e   f   g
22  12  0   32  28  21  33
```

This is written more for clarity than conciseness. It should be POSIX awk conformant. A letter line without the corresponding number line at the end of the file isn't handled properly.